# Hive 3.1 cannot create external table that copy schema from internal/managed table

Tags: hive, external-tables, hdp, internal-tables

we try to make an external hive table which its schema is similar from existing internal/managed table and the data for ecternal will be inserted next step.

Below the code to create external table with copy schema of managed table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sls_test_ext like sls_test
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
LOCATION "/bla/bla/";
```

But when its executed, it returns as below

```
ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:sp2020.sls_test_ext cannot be declared transactional because it's an external table)
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20201111233927_593d38ff-39ed-412e-b128-41d949a3a476); Time taken: 0.017 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:sp2020.sls_test_ext cannot be declared transactional because it's an external table) (state=08S01,code=1)
```

Then we try to modif the code above as below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sls_test_ext like sls_test
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
LOCATION "/bla/bla/"
TBLPROPERTIES ("transactional"="false");
```

It will returns same error.
Is there any missing code or there is some hive configuration to be changed

NB: the managed table is created automatically using sqoop import hive-table
?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution:

**Managed Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE sls_test(<columns>)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

**External Table:**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sls_test_ext
LIKE sls_test
LOCATION '/bla/bla/';
```

Comment: what if the managed table is created by sqoop import hive-table? I am sorry to mention it before and I've update it in question

Comment: That is not an issue. Only thing you need to looked into is - the delimiter used for the managed table must match with delimiter used in file stored in HDFS location.